How Can I Capture Dynamic Model Movement with Sensors in PyDrake During Simulation?
I'm running a simulation in PyDrake and trying to capture sensor outputs that reflect the model's movement over time. I've set up the simulation using ForcedPublish and Simulator and am collecting sensor data on a separate thread. However, the sensor output only captures the initial position of the model and does not update with the ongoing simulation.
I used the following code to obtain point clouds from the sensor during the simulation:
def get_point_cloud(diagram: Diagram, normals=True, down_sample=True):
    # Obtain the root context from the diagram
    root_context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
    
    # Obtain the context for the specific subsystem (e.g., 'plant')
    plant = diagram.GetSubsystemByName("plant")
    plant_context = plant.GetMyContextFromRoot(root_context)
    
    # Create a context for the diagram to ensure the output ports are evaluated correctly
    diagram_context = diagram.GetMyContextFromRoot(root_context)
    
        
    pcd = []
    number_of_camera = list_camera_ports(diagram)
    min_val = 5
    max_val = 5
    for i in range(number_of_camera):
        # cloud = diagram.GetOutputPort(f"camera{i}_point_cloud").Eval(plant_context)
        # pcd.append(cloud.Crop(lower_xyz=[-min_val, -min_val, -min_val], upper_xyz=[max_val, max_val, max_val]))

        # Access the output port from the diagram context
        output_port = diagram.GetOutputPort(f"camera{i}_point_cloud")
        
        # Evaluate the output port using the diagram context
        cloud = output_port.Eval(diagram_context)
        # Crop the point cloud
        pcd.append(cloud.Crop(lower_xyz=[-min_val, -min_val, -min_val], upper_xyz=[max_val, max_val, max_val]))
    
        if normals:
            pcd[i].EstimateNormals(radius=1, num_closest=50)
            camera = plant.GetModelInstanceByName(f"camera{i}")
            body = plant.GetBodyByName("base", camera)
            X_C = plant.EvalBodyPoseInWorld(plant_context, body)
            pcd[i].FlipNormalsTowardPoint(X_C.translation())

    # Merge point clouds
    merged_pcd = Concatenate(pcd)
    down_sampled_pcd = merged_pcd if not down_sample else merged_pcd.VoxelizedDownSample(voxel_size=0.005)

    # Retrieve color data if available
    colors = np.array(down_sampled_pcd.rgbs()) if down_sampled_pcd.has_rgbs() else np.ones((len(down_sampled_pcd.xyzs()), 3)) * [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
    if not down_sampled_pcd.has_rgbs():
        print("Color data is not available in PointCloud.")

    return down_sampled_pcd, colors

This is a code for setup camera
builder = DiagramBuilder()
    plant: MultibodyPlant
    plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(
        builder, time_step=0.001)
    parser = Parser(plant)
    ConfigureParser(parser)
    parser.AddModels("parcli/sdf/parcli/parcli.sdf") # parcli robot definition defined here
    parser.AddModels("parcli/sensor_model/camera.dmd.yaml")  # sensor/camera definition defined here
    ladder = Ladder(n_rungs = 20,spacing=0.25,z_offset=0.25)
    ladder.add_to_world(plant)
    plant.Finalize()

    # creating Rgbd sensors 
    AddRgbdSensors(builder, plant, scene_graph)
    sensor = plant.GetModelInstanceByName("camera0")

I expected the sensor outputs to update dynamically, reflecting the model’s movement throughout the simulation. However, the output only shows the model's initial position. I’ve ruled out the possibility of the graph not updating. How can I ensure that the sensors capture the model's movement as it occurs in the simulation?

Evaluating output ports manually, like you're doing in that example (and which I do in many examples in the manipulation notes) is natural for making sure that you understand the outputs from a system, but it's not the intended way to work with output ports during a simulation. For that, you will be building up a Diagram with other Systems which connect to the output port and do, e.g. the point cloud processing.
You might want to look at the clutter clearing example from the notes, which does exactly this type of point cloud processing inside the GraspSelection system.
